# How to Switch Camera in Google Hangouts on Android 11?

Tags: camera, google-hangouts, video-calling

Google Hangouts shows an icon to switch between front and back cameras (or move it from the front to the back) but is there a way to choose between cameras on a phone with a multi-camera setup?

Comment: As far as I know Hangouts is EOL at September 30, 2021 https://www.xda-developers.com/google-hangouts-replace-free-google-chat-2021/

Comment: That's strange. Phones released last month come with Hangouts! Another even more frustrating tidbit is that may older phones have plenty of Google apps that were discontinued and can't be removed on a non-rooted phone! This means people will be trapped for years for software that has potential software vulnerabilities and keeping their storage used too boot. Some can be 'disabled' which presumably prevents some software vulnerability but this shows the ridicule of preventing regular users from removing certain apps.